# Installing Numpy developmental over anaconda

Tags: python, numpy

I'm pondering switching over to Anaconda from my vanilla Python in OSX. I know Anaconda brings its own NumPy. I was wondering if it was possible to make the GitHub version of NumPy the default version, or if Anaconda only works with its own version.

Comment: Anaconda still lets you install whatever you want, it is just a pre-built collection of Python packages with a package manager. There is a list of anaconda packages (http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/) (latest Numpy is 1.8.1).

Comment: If you want to use the development version of numpy you'll have to compile it yourself, but should be able to do so easily on top of any Anaconda installation.

Comment: Jaime, I'm in the process of compiling it from a github checkout but it's giving me errors. Is it just as simple of running the Numpy setup script from the cloned repository?

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda installs python just like it already is on your system, only to a different location. It allows you to choose what packages you want to install. If you want to replace one you can go into the site-packages folder (`Anaconda/lib/site-packages`) and do so. In my experience, Anaconda was well worth the switch.